# Fragments and inheritances

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change my main activity's frame view with different fragments I'm creating.

My onNavigationItemSelected:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
         fragment  = new FragmentOne();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
         fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

and my fragment is :

```
package com.example.tombushmits.pilot;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.tombushmits.pilot.R;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    public FragmentOne(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup         container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
}


package com.example.tombushmits.pilot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.tombushmits.pilot.R;

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

public FragmentTwo(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
}
}
```

but I'm getting an error :

> Error:(116, 26) error: incompatible types required: Fragment found:
>   FragmentOne

Comment: Verify that you're using the same Fragment classes. Look at the import statements, it could be that one is using android.app.Fragment and the other is using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: ^ Agreed, could you include the imports for your activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FragmentOne` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. In your `MainActivity`, you're using `getFragmentManager()`, which works with `android.app.Fragment` classes. You should either make `FragmentOne` inherit from `android.app.Fragment`, or use `getSupportFragmentManager()` inside `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
    // Handle the camera action
} else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
     fragment  = new FragmentOne();

} else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
     fragment = new FragmentOne();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

}
```

Here, you were trying to use "FragmentTwo" ,but it is not there, so update the code as I have shown above